# Jenkins artifactory plugin - identify that files are not there

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I'm using Jenkins Artifactory plugin to publish artifacts as well as download required artifacts. When downloading artifacts, what needs to be downloaded is determined dynamically while the Jenkins pipeline is executing.

If the artifacts that need to be downloaded are not there in artifactory, I want to abort the pipeline with a corresponding error message.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to determine presence or absence of files.  `Artifactory.download` call does not throw any exceptions if requested files are not there and doesn't return any meaningful information.

Of course, I can always check whether or not files exist after the download, but I was hoping for some "native" way. So, how can I verify after the `download` call whether or not my requested artifacts have been downloaded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, there are 2 options:

Option 1:
Use the failNoOp flag. It'll fail your pipeline in case of 0 downloads:

```
server.download spec: downloadSpec, failNoOp: true
```

Option 2:
In the latest Jenkins Artifactory plugin v3.2.0 there is a new feature to list downloaded/uploaded files:

```
def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
server.download spec: downloadSpec, buildInfo: buildInfo
if (buildInfo.getDependencies().size() == 0) {
 // Do your magic
}
```

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-ScriptedPipelineSyntax).

Comment: Ah! That's it! I was expecting it to return an instance of downloadSpec with the information.  Instead it's populating the instance I'm passing to it.